# How to tell if a user is logged in?

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I would like to tell if a user is logged in or not.

```
if [ "$(who | grep -wq "$1")" == 0 ]
echo $1 "is logged in"
```

`"$(who | grep -w "$1")"` is equal to 0 if grep finds $1 (a username) in the list(who). So if the user is in the list, he or she is logged in.
What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

grep doesn't *print* 0, which is what your script checks for. Its *exit code* is 0. To check the exit code it's simply:

```
if who | grep -wq "$1"; then
    echo "$1 is logged in"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash, `$?` is used to save the exit code. you can use it to check the exit code of grep.

```
who | grep -wq "$1"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$1 is logged in"
fi
```